# Trouble with changing value of array in function using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

I am trying to write code that will prompt the user for a string, and then print the string. It will then use the function 'initialize' to change every value in the array to 'a' except the last value, which will be changed to '\0'. The calling function will then print the updated string.

Here is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize(char (*firstString)[50]);

void main(void)
{
   char firstString[50];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", firstString);
    printf("%s", firstString);
    initialize(&firstString);
    printf("%s", firstString);
}

void
initialize(char (*firstString)[50])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        *firstString[i] = 'a';
        *firstString[49] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the working code. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize(char firstString[50]);

void main(void)
{
   char firstString[50];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", firstString);
    printf("%s", firstString);
    initialize(firstString);
    printf("%s", firstString);
}

void
initialize(char firstString[50])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        memset(firstString, 'a', 49);
    firstString[49] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: You should get a warning with -Wall -Wextra, that tells you what the problem is.

Comment: `*firstString[i] ` and precedence....

Comment: *firstSring[i] is a **  pointer use only 1 pointer

Comment: You don't need to pass a pointer to the array, arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, and you can use indexing (like `firstString[i]`) on pointers as well as arrays.

Comment: And you should learn about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Thou shalt not compile without `-Wall` `-Werror`.

Comment: Lastly, do you really need to set the string terminator for *all* iterations of the loop? And why not use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) to set all the bytes instead of your own loop?

Comment: You should read more about main and its return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` has higher precedence than `*` so `*firstString[x]` is parsed as `*(firstString[x])`. See [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)
.

So you need to write`(*firstString)[x]` to get the correct precedence.

Also, your function could be written simply as:

```
void
initialize(char (*firstString)[50])
{
    memset(firstString, 'a', 49);
    (*firstString)[49] = '\0';
}
```